# How add external connection file with java project to allow user to change database, server username and pass

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I have developed a java database application with netbeans and sql server 2008 Here is my java db connection class file.

```
public java.sql.Connection connectToDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=pwd12345;" +
        "databaseName=SMS_DB;";

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        java.sql.Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();

    } catch(SQLException se){System.out.println(se.getMessage());}
      return connection;
 }
```

in this way, it not allow user to change Database name, server username and password after build it. But I want to add an external file xml or properties file to allow user to change database, username and password.

any easy way to add this option in my app?

Thank you,

H M Masum Billah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple to use `.properties` file for that.

Assume you have `config.properties`:

```
db.host=http://localhost:5432/dbname
db.login=postgres
db.password=12345678
```

You can read this file from Java like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
dbProperties.load(fis);
String host = dbProperties.getProperty("db.host");
String login = dbProperties.getProperty("db.login");
String password = dbProperties.getProperty("db.password");
```

Now you can use it to create your `Connection`.

It's just an example. In real application you should think about `config.properties` file path (here I don't specify any absolute path and you can put this file in your project's root folder, but in real application this may not suitable), close `FileInputStream` correctly etc.

If you want to use `.xml` file for this, you should take a look at [dom4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j/) or any other library to parse your XML.

Comment: Can you help to set file path for "config.properties" so I can try this.

Comment: I think if you put this file in your project's root folder the code above will work. Try it. Anyway you should read about resources, maybe that would be helpful: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/